# Join query in Symfony 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony

I'm new in Symfony and I have 2 entities (not me who created them):

- 1st entity: test1 (id,test2_id)
- 2nd entity: test2 (id,label)

I want to create the query that select from test where `test2.label = 1`.

```
$Websites = $this->_em
    ->createQuery("
        SELECT w
        FROM \Bundle\Entity\test1 t1
        JOIN t1.test2 t2
        WHERE t2.label=1")
    ->getResult();
```

But I got an error:

> Bundle\Entity\test1 has no association named test2

Is there the solution or another way to make it work.

Comment: Some basic examples for you. [Doctrine createQueryBuilder and createQuery examples](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/znlh/doctrine-createquerybuilder-and-createuery-examples)

Comment: Please, attach your `test1` and `test2` entity classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$Websites = $this->_em
->createQuery("
    SELECT w
    FROM \Bundle\Entity\test1 t1
    JOIN \Bundle\Entity\test2 t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.test2_id AND t2.label=1")
->getResult();
```

You can also use `createQueryBuilder` method

Answer (score 0):

Using **createQueryBuilder** you can do with the following

```
$labelValue = 1;

/* Get the EntityManager Resource */
$em = $this->getDoctrine->getManager();

$em->getRepository('AppBundle:test1')
   ->createQueryBuilder('t1')
   ->select('t1.w') /*Here you can select respective table columns */
   ->innerJoin('t1.test2_id', 't2')
   ->where('t2.label = :label') /* if label value coming from external value else ->where('t2.label = 1') and omit next line */
   ->setParameter('label',$labelValue) /*In case if your label value coming for external value */
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();
```